# Which countries contribute the most to the Tor source code?

Tags: source-code, development

Amongst the developers working on the Tor source code, which countries have the maximum representation in terms of number of contributors and overall contributions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used git plus some shell to count the number of commits (`git log --shortstat | awk -F: '/Author: / { print $2 }' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n`). According to that more than 14000 commits came from Roger or Nick. This accounts for >80% of all commits (>17000). Some 1500 come from german speaking regions (Germany, Austria, Switzerland). There are 122 different names and email addresses committed some code. Most of them seem to come from the US.

I would guess that somewhat around 85% of the commits comes from the US, 9-10% comes from german speaking countries.